# Why does the python run like this?

Tags: python, list

```
def print():
    info = [0,0] 
    map = [[info for col in range(n+1)] for row in range(n+1)]
    
    map[1][1][0] = 1 # i hope this ==> map[1][1] = [1,0]
```

but result this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgHAG.png)

Comment: for starters, do not use map as it is an inbuilt function you are overwriting. second, you are just repeating the content of info all through the iterations

Comment: Because you **put the same list** inside multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info` represents the *same list* for each result in the comprehension. When this list is modified later, it appears to affect all the results because it is the *same shared object* that is modified.

One way is to avoid the issue is to create a *new* list explicitly using a literal:

```
map = [[[0, 1] for col in range(n+1)] for row in range(n+1)]
```

Or, as Keith pointed out, create a *copy* of the original list:

```
map = [[info[:] for col in range(n+1)] for row in range(n+1)]
```

Also, don’t use the same-name as built-ins — ie. rename `map` to something else.

Comment: Could also copy the info array: `info[:]`.

Comment: nitpick: use the term `list` here. Yes, it is a dynamic array, but array in Python generally implies *numpy* array.

Comment: Updated to use ‘list’.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the array `info`:

```
map = [[info.copy() for col in range(n+1)] for row in range(n+1)]
```

So that it doesn't refer to the same object.

**Note: Don't name variables as keyword names, such as `map`.**

Instead something like:

```
variable = [[info.copy() for col in range(n+1)] for row in range(n+1)]
```